# Selenium WebDrivder ebDriverException: unknown error: Element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (242, 340). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.79)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JE83S2H', ip: '192.168.1.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba15..., userDataDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.79, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 26267f18d3cdeb5501be4f1fd01a5562

Answer (score 0):

> You might get this error due to various reasons

```
i) element is not yet loaded - increase the wait time
ii) element is not visible - add explicit wait time
iii) check if the element is being hidden by any pop up on the page before you try to click.
```

> If you don't see any pop ups on the page. try adding a wait before the
>   click operation (Thread.sleep(5000)) to check if that works. If it
>   does, change the implicit wait to more relevant explicit wait.

Comment: Already User thread.sleep(60000) but not working

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <path id="spot_image 1" d="m 484.36 36.892 h -464.38 c -10.856 0 -19.976 9.668 -19.976 20.524 v 299.5 c 0 10.86 9.12 18.6 19.976 18.6 h 118.06 c 0 -63 51.2 -114.12 114.13 -114.12 c 62.936 0 114.14 51.124 114.14 114.12 h 118.06 c 10.856 0 19.644 -7.744 19.644 -18.6 v -299.5 c 0 -10.856 -8.788 -20.524 -19.644 -20.524 z m -92.856 135.66 l -74.456 74.472 l -113.33 -113.32 c -1.54 -1.54 -4.024 -1.54 -5.564 0 l -71.884 71.88 l -32.816 -32.812 c -1.536 -1.54 -4.172 -1.54 -5.708 0 l

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <path id="spot_image 1"  ==Solve issue